# How to add obtain a information form another file and use in a variable

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch program which needs to obtain &  use 3 variables as shown below.

```
SET ID-BLUE=X:\ID-BLUE.TXT
SET ID-RED=Y:\ID-RED.TXT
SET ID-GREEN=Z:\ID-GREEN.TXT
```

The data can be obtained from a user prepared resource file C:\DISKCOLOR.TXT, contents which read:

```
ID-BLUE=X:\ID-BLUE.TXT
ID-RED=Y:\ID-RED.TXT
ID-GREEN=Z:\ID-GREEN.TXT
```

What commands do I need to get the batch file to automatically obtain this info from the resource file and set the variables within the batch file for use as ongoing execution of the batch file.

Each `C:\DISKCOLOR.TXT` file could differ but would have the same colors and file names as example except for differing drive letters or maybe a `UNC` path.

If desirable, it would be possible to break the single resource file into 3 separate resource files of one line each.

This batch file will probably be run on both XP, XP Pro, Win 7, Win 8 machines.

Answer (score 0):

It's a one-liner:

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a in (c:\diskcolor.txt) do set %%a=%%b
```

Comment: THANK YOU. However, both answers produced the same results. The echo commands produced an empty variable on all. The exact error mess was "ECHO IS OFF (LISTED 3 TIMES). I copied and pasted your suggestion into the batch file and tried both suggestions. Your continued help appreciated.

Comment: There's more than one way to skin a cat.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the structure `VAR=VALUE` in you text File.
Juste set the line as it is :

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "c:\diskcolor.txt"') do set %%a

echo %ID-BLUE%
echo %ID-RED%
echo %ID-GREEN%
```

Comment: THANK YOU. However, both answers produced the same results. The echo commands produced an empty variable on all. The exact error mess was "ECHO IS OFF (LISTED 3 TIMES). I copied and pasted your suggestion into the batch file and tried both suggestions. Your continued help appreciated.

Comment: You are executing it within a loop, aren't you?  Use delayed expansion.

Comment: sorry, but if your explanation are right, Magoo is solution or my solution work perfectly. If you get an empty variable, please check your `c:\diskcolor.txt`, and look what is in....

Comment: replace the `echo` lines with `set id` to be sure, that the variables are set correctly

Comment: Stephen: Adding the SET ID-BLUE, SET ID-RED, SET ID-GREEN prior to the ECHO commands enabled both of the suggested commands  to work equally well.  A thank you to all. Stephen enabled the piece to fall into place.